# Every pressed Button on Listview opening pressed and 5th position

Tags: android

I am developing small Puzzle android app having 102 puzzles on database. I used `Adapter` with 2 `TextViews` and 1 `Button` for `ListView`.

In Adapter I have puzzl as `TextView` for showing puzzles, answer as `TextView` for showing answers (on xml it its made `GONE` by default). When user presses answer_button `TextView` answer shows answer(`answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`).

Everything is working fine but i found that there is a problem. If i press button for 1st answer to see on `ListView`, it is showing 1st answer but from below also opening other answers for example 5th, 11th, 16th and so on. If i press button for 2nd answer it is showing 2nd answer and 7th, 12th and so on. All is opening.

I want to make button must show only selected answer for user. Please help me, show me where is my mistake on adapter or on `ListView`? Thank you very much.

```
    public class PuzzleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        List<Puzzles> puzzles;

    public PuzzleAdapter(Context context1, List<Puzzles> p1){
        this.context=context1;
        this.puzzles =p1;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return puzzles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return puzzles.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (view == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.puzzle_adapter, null);
        }

        final Puzzles puzz = this.puzzles.get(i);

        TextView puzzl=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.puzzl);
        puzzl.setText(puzz.getZagad());

        final TextView answer=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.answer);
        answer.setText(puzz.getOtveti());

        final Button answer_button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.answer_button);

        answer_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

My main class where i call adapter

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DbHelper dbHelper;
    List<Puzzles> puzzles = new ArrayList<Puzzles>();
    ListView listView;
    PuzzleAdapter puzzleAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        dbHelper.createDB();

        puzzles = dbHelper.zagadki(this);
        puzzleAdapter = new PuzzleAdapter(this, puzzles);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(puzzleAdapter);
    }
}
```

here i call from database

```
    //    public List<Puzzles> zagadki(int id){
    public List<Puzzles> zagadki(Context context){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<Puzzles> puzzles = new ArrayList<Puzzles>();
//        String s = "select * from zagad where _id=" + id;
        String s = "select * from zagad";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(s, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Puzzles puzzle = new Puzzles();
                puzzle.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
                puzzle.setZagad(cursor.getString(1));
                puzzle.setOtveti(cursor.getString(2));
                puzzles.add(puzzle);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return puzzles;
    }
```

Comment: Remove null check and try
        if (view == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.puzzle_adapter, null);
        }

Comment: brother thank you your answer solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

As you have taken directly view and maintain therefore this issue occur,

So use holder class and then manage it check my below code,

```
   public class ViewHolder {

      TextView puzzl;
      TextView answer;
      Button answer_button;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

       View row = view;
       ViewHolder holder= null;

       if (row == null)
       {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.puzzle_adapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.puzzl=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.puzzl);
            holder.answer=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.answer);
            holder.answer_button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.answer_button);
            row.setTag(holder);

       }
       else
       {
            holder = (AppInfoHolder)row.getTag();
       }
              holder.puzzl.setText(puzz.getZagad());
              holder.answer.setText(puzz.getOtveti());
              holder.answer_button.setTag(holder);

              holder.answer_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View view) {
                         ViewHolder selectedHolder = (View Holder) view.getTag();

                         selectedHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       }
               });

       return row;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much brother for an explanation, it helped me much

Comment: @AkramPulatov, If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.

Comment: hello, where is this green check?

Comment: you will get it at start point of this anser, below the number 0, you can upvote this answer if it helps you and accept it if it solved your query,

So below upvote and downvote there is a yes symbol which you can click to make it green.