# How to handle ListView containing EditText and CheckBox on each row item (Android)

Tags: android, listview

[image]

i am trying to implement that, when click on edit button (shown last two in image)
then that row should be editable mode with specific edit text and then click on save button that updates value should be change.

But major issue is that when click on edit button that row is editable but in bottom some other row is also randomly editable automatically and i cant handle this .....totaly frustrated with this issue please give any solution for this.

another issue is that after edit value when scrool list then updated value change and orignal display there ...so how can i manage all that thing is there any demo  which match with my requirement plsss help......

Comment: Check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156924/every-pressed-button-on-listview-opening-pressed-and-5th-position/38157231?noredirect=1#comment63821724_38157231

Comment: Show your adapter code.

Comment: hello i have upload image of my custom adapter plss give any solution ...

Answer (score 0):

[image: adapter]
adpater class

[image: adapter]

getview method
[image: adapter]

save button click
[image: adapter]

edit button click

[image: adapter]

checkbox event

[image: adapter]

delete button click
[image: adapter]

position handle logic

[image: adapter]

position handle logic

Comment: Please post code in the normal way as text. You want OP to retype this?